# Laravel polymorphic many-to-many not detaching?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, polymorphic-relationship

I have a polymorphic many to many `User`/`Location` - `Group` relationship, but I'm having a time getting the basic unit testing to pass.

```php
/** @test */
public function it_can_have_groups()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $group = factory(Group::class)->create();

    $user->addToGroup($group);
    $this->assertCount(1, $user->groups);  // true

    $user->removeFromGroup($group);
    $this->assertCount(0, $user->groups);  // false
}
```

These methods simply call `attach` and `detach` as per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):

> To remove a many-to-many relationship record, use the detach method. The detach method will delete the appropriate record out of the intermediate table; however, both models will remain in the database

```php
public function addToGroup(Group $group)
{
    $this->groups()->attach($group->id);
}

public function removeFromGroup(Group $group)
{
    $this->groups()->detach($group->id));
    dump($group->users());                 // []
}
```

So it seems to work (?), but only from the groups side, and the assertion still fails.  Why, and what should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be as simple as the model you are testing having stale relationships. Try this:

```
/** @test */
public function it_can_have_groups()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $group = factory(Group::class)->create();

    $user->addToGroup($group);
    $this->assertCount(1, $user->groups->fresh());  // true

    $user->removeFromGroup($group);
    $this->assertCount(0, $user->groups->fresh());  // false
}
```